# Retrieve scan results from HP Fortify Security Center

Tags: sql, security, fortify

I am trying to provide a consolidated method of retrieving the results of the last scan for each project in HP Fortify Security Center.

I have gone the route of querying the fortifySSC database and am falling a little short. Has anyone ever attempted to do this by way of a SQL query?

I would be happy to provide the query that I have thus far, if needed.

Or if anyone has an idea on how to accomplish this via the command line, I'd be in interested in that, too.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get the query I needed via the SQL Profiler, so that's how I resolved this.

Answer (score 1):

i´ve never done this in the CLI via SQL commands. But there is a utility called fortifyclient that is able to download the latest FPRs from a project. if you want to automate things, fortifyclient can handle token-based authentication. works for us perfectly in our CI environment.

Comment: Think I may have figured it out. I just ran SQL Profiler while I looked at the trend report and that gave me the query I was looking for.

Comment: We use the fortifyclient in our CI environment as well. I did get the query I needed via the SQL Profiler, so that's how I resolved this.

Comment: The reports are just BIRT reports, you can download them and look at the SQL queries they perform. But I agree about fortifyclient, much less hassle when it comes to different versions with different schemas and is the advised way to go rather than doing anything with the database manually.